# How to achieve http get in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

using typescript and angular get data using rest API .i am new to the angular 2 and  typescript .please any one help me to achieve this in my application

thanks

Comment: Angular has a very good documentation and starter guides. Please read these first, before asking unspecific questions. https://angular.io/

Comment: Like @Hinrich said, Angular has a whole tutorial chapter dedicated to `HTTP`. Read everything in this page, and you should be good. https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use  this below code  that may be help you

```
public vehicleinfo:any=[]
//query is your rest api url
getVehicleinfo(query){

            if (this.vehicleinfo) {
        // already loaded data  
       // console.log("already data loaded vehicleinfo") ;
        return Promise.resolve(this.vehicleinfo);
      }
    // don't have the data yet
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      // We're using Angular HTTP provider to request the data,
      // then on the response, it'll map the JSON data to a parsed JS object.
      // Next, we process the data and resolve the promise with the new data.
        this.http.get(query)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          // we've got back the raw data, now generate the core schedule data
          // and save the data for later reference
          this.vehicleinfo = data;
          resolve(this.vehicleinfo);
        });
    });
  }
```